# Nvidia driver problem on suspend Linux Mint

Tags: linux, nvidia, suspend

I have problem little problem with Linux Mint 17.3, I've install Nvidia 352.63 driver and everything works fine until I suspend. When I resume after suspend animations start lagging, while I'm scrolling screen is lagging too, I see fps drop too. After restart pc everything works fine to next suspend. I have geforce 860M on my laptop.

@Edit

I've reinstall my system to Netrunner and I didn't see such lagging like was at Linux Mint, but when i go back to mint after hibernate I see big fps drop, smooth scrolling don't work properly, only lags all time. Why on Mint is huge fps drop but on Netrunner it isn't so much

Answer (score 1):

Research the Geforce's Nvidia and Intel modes of operation if not already familiar. Ensure are not using Nouveau after the suspend-resume. Try blacklisting the Nouveau module. Links below are from a couple years ago but might be helpful: [Switch to Nvidia from Nouveau](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hNnanyEGvdOgkLh58wfvItBCGNv3fDkGccGBKRTxgvo/edit?usp=sharing),
[Rough notes from GeForce 675](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fKWUodNt_3BRBr2ZMKysM-PqzEZ-nhWhTikuwpEFS_s/edit?usp=sharing)

Nouveau may be loaded by the kernel before the blacklist takes effect. There is a boot parameter to type into Grub, but Nouveau issue is just one possibility. The X11 log, /var/log/Xorg.0.log or similar is worth a look.

Comment: I blacklist Nouveau but it didnt help me, is there any other possibilities to repair that ?